# error: cannot find 'CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent' in scope

Tags: swift

I am trying to use the function `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` in Swift on Windows 10.
However, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find 'CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent' in scope
```

I tried importing `CoreFoundation` but this yields the following error:

```
error: no such module 'CoreFoundation'
```

How can I use this function on Windows? I am using Swift version 5.6.3.

Comment: What swift version are you using?

Comment: @Sweeper I am using Swift version 5.6.3.

Comment: Did you import Foundation?

Comment: @AchidF Yes, I tried importing Foundation, to no avail.